# error:invalide operands to binary + (have 'float' and 'float **')

Tags: c, function, multidimensional-array, floating-point, declaration

```
    void clc_moy_mdl(int n, int m,float *mt[3][30])
{
    float s;
    int i,j;
    s=0;

    remplire_matrice(n,m,tab,mt);
    for(j=1;i<=n;j++)
    {
        for(i=1;i<=(m-1);i++)
        {
            s =s+ mt[i][j];
            printf("%f",s);
        }
        mt[i][j]= s /(m);
    }
}
```

this is a procedure from a program that I write it
I have an error in line 12
error:invalid operands to binary + (have 'float' and 'float **')
How can I solve it?

Comment: `mt` is an array of arrays of *pointers* to `float`. That means e.g. `mt[i][j]` is a *pointer* to `float`, not a `float` value.

Comment: By the way, you *do* know that array indexes are zero-based? So that an array of `n` elements will have indexes from `0` to `n - 1` (inclusive).

Answer (score 1):

The parameter `mt` is declared as having the array type `float *[3][30]`

```
void clc_moy_mdl(int n, int m,float *mt[3][30])
```

Thus the expression `mt[i][j]` has the type `float *` and in these statements

```
s =s+ mt[i][j];
```

and

```
mt[i][j]= s /(m);
```

there are used incorrectly operations with a pointer and a float.

Either instead you have to write

```
s =s + *mt[i][j];
```

and

```
*mt[i][j]= s /(m);
```

or to declare the function like

```
void clc_moy_mdl(int n, int m,float mt[3][30])
```

Pay attention to that array indices start from 0. So it seems the for loops like this

```
for(j=1;i<=n;j++)
```

in your program can produce undefined behavior. You should write

```
for(j=0;i<n;j++)
```

Answer (score 0):

`float *mt[3][30]` defines `mt` as 2D array of pointers to `float`.

Remove the `*`

You can also use the passed sizes to declare this parameter.

```
void clc_moy_mdl(size_t n, size_t m,float mt[n][m])
{
    float s = 0.0f;
    size_t i,j;

    for(j = 0; i < n; j++)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            s += mt[i][j];
            printf("%f", s);
        }
        mt[i][j]= s / m;
    }
}
```

Remember that indexes start from `0` and use the correct types for sizes (`size_t`)